# Conditionally Require Data in SharePoint List Columns (cannot be blank)

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, validation

I am working on a List where if a certain entry is edited/marked as "Closed" in the **Status** column, then the **Resolution Date** cannot be blank, and should not let the user save the changes (Stop Editing the list).

[image]

I've tried doing this in Settings > Validation Settings with no success.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use client side rendering (CSR) ans JSLink to accomplish this.  With CSR you can attach a piece of Javascript to a column or to a (edit/new) form. It's also possible to create conditional validations and/or toggle field required properties (based values from other fields).

Most popular samples online are here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

This sample is about formatting a field but it is the same idea. Replace the formatting logic by your (extra) validation rules. 
http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2014/js-link-csr-view-conditional-formatting/